# Is there an easy way of installing madwifi drivers in Fedora 17?

Tags: fedora

Long time ago you could easily install madwifi drivers for atheros wireless cards as they were found in the livna (or RPM fusion?) repositories. Today I cannot find any guide or even mentions when googling it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The madwifi driver is [deprecated nowadays](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/madwifi) in favor of [`ath5k`](http://madwifi-project.org/wiki/About/ath5k) and [`ath9k`](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k). So there should be no need to recompile or install additional drivers nowadays.